# Как в java поменять image методом mouseClicked

Tags: java

Делаю крестики нолики на java.
С помощью  класса image добавил массив тайлов

```
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawImage(grid, 0, 0, null);

        int offset_X = 0;
        int offset_Y = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                offset_X = i * 100;
                offset_Y = j * 100;

                g.drawImage(tile_Empty, 0 + offset_X, 0 + offset_Y, null);
            }
        }
    }
```

загрузил тайлы (tile_Empty) и добавил их в массив Image[][] board = new Image[3][3];

```
 private void loadImage() 
    {

        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("src/resources/Board.png");
        grid = ii.getImage();

        ImageIcon tile = new ImageIcon("src/resources/Tile.png");
        tile_Empty = tile.getImage();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                board[j][i] = tile_Empty;
            }
        }
    }
```

с помощью метода mouseClicked пытаюсь поменять картинку

```
addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me)
        {

            System.out.println(me);

            Point p = new Point(me.getPoint());
            System.out.println("Component coords: x = " + p.x + ", y = " + p.y);

            int inX = p.x;
            int inY = p.y;

            System.out.println(" - inX == " + inX +  " inY == " + inY);

            // column inX
            if (inX > 0 && inX <= 100) {
                col = 0;
            }
            if (inX > 100 && inX <= 200) {
                col = 1;
            }
            if (inX > 200 && inX <= 300) {
                col = 2;
            }

            // row inY
            if (inY > 0 && inY <= 100) {
                row = 0;
            }
            if (inY > 100 && inY <= 200) {
                row = 1;
            }
            if (inY > 200 && inY <= 300) {
                row = 2;
            }


            ImageIcon _X = new ImageIcon("src/resources/X.png");

            board[col][row] = _X.getImage();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Можно сделать так...

mport java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

class Board extends JPanel
{
    private final int B_WIDTH = 300;
    private final int B_HEIGHT = 300;

    private boolean nTurn = false;

    private JFrame owner;

    private Image grid;
    private Image tile_Empty;
    private Image tile_X;
    private Image tile_O;
    public Image[][] board = new Image[3][3];

    int col = -1;
    int row = -1;


    public Image im,im2;
    public Image current;//добавлено



    public Board( JFrame inOwner )
    {
        owner = inOwner;

        initBoard();
    }


    private void initBoard() {

//        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(B_WIDTH, B_HEIGHT));

        loadImage();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
//                System.out.println(" - tile_Empty -  " + tile_Empty );
                board[j][i] = tile_Empty;
            }
        }

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event)
            {
                current = im; //добавлено
//                current = im2; //добавлено

                System.out.println(event);
//                System.out.println(" - tile_Empty -  " + tile_Empty );
//                System.out.println("INITIAL_X - " + INITIAL_X);

                Point p = new Point(event.getPoint());
//                System.out.println("Component coords: x = " + p.x + ", y = " + p.y);

                int inX = p.x;
                int inY = p.y;

//                System.out.println(" - inX == " + inX + " inY == " + inY);

                // column inX
                if (inX > 0 && inX <= 100) {
                    col = 0;
                }
                if (inX > 100 && inX <= 200) {
                    col = 1;
                }
                if (inX > 200 && inX <= 300) {
                    col = 2;
                }

                // row inY
                if (inY > 0 && inY <= 100) {
                    row = 0;
                }
                if (inY > 100 && inY <= 200) {
                    row = 1;
                }
                if (inY > 200 && inY <= 300) {
                    row = 2;
                }

                board[col][row] = current;
                updateUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawImage(grid, 0, 0, null);
//        g.drawImage(tile_X, 0, 0, null);
//        g.drawImage(tile_O, 0, 0, null);
//        g.drawImage(tile_Empty, 0, 0, null);

        int offset_X = 0;
        int offset_Y = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                offset_X = j * 100;
                offset_Y = i * 100;

//                Image tile = board[j][i];
//                g.drawImage(tile, 0 + offset_X, 0 + offset_Y, null);

                if(board[j][i] != null)
                {
                    Image tile = board[j][i];
                    g.drawImage(tile, 0 + offset_X, 0 + offset_Y, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void loadImage()
    {
        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("src/resources/Board.png");
        grid = ii.getImage();

//        ImageIcon tile = new ImageIcon("src/resources/Tile.png");
//        tile_Empty = tile.getImage();

//        im=ImageIO.read(new File("src/resources/X.png"));
//        im2=ImageIO.read(new File("src/resources/O.png"));
//        current = im; //добавлено

        ImageIcon _X = new ImageIcon("src/resources/X.png");
        im = _X.getImage();


        ImageIcon _O = new ImageIcon("src/resources/O.png");
        im2 = _O.getImage();
    }
}

import javax.swing.JFrame;

class Tic_Tac_Toe extends JFrame
{

    public Tic_Tac_Toe()
    {
        initUI();

    }


    private void initUI()
    {
        add(new Board(this));

        pack();

        setTitle("My_Tic_Tac_Toe");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Tic_Tac_Toe frame=new Tic_Tac_Toe();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```